# @OnDelete not working correctly with @Inheritance and @ManyToOne combination

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

When I delete the D object I would like to delete associated data in C(including parent data) as well. In the below code when I deleted the D, C part deleted successfully but the parent(A) related part still exists in the database.

I have seen the https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13299 issue, but I don't know it is the same issue or not, if yes then what could I do as a workaround?

```
@Entity
class D {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class A {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   private String common;
}

@Entity
public class B extends A {
}

@Entity
public class C extends A {

   @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "d_id")
   @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
   private D d;
}
```

Assume that getter and setters are implemented.

Comment: Why are you using @OnDelete?

Comment: I couldn't define the bidirectional relationship between D and C. I would like to delete C when D is deleted which way I could accomplish it without @OnDelete ?

Comment: And why don't you delete D? OnDelete is on the database side and may cause this problems because the database has no inheritance!

Comment: I am deleting D, but after that, I am expecting that C should be deleted somehow, and I am trying to achieve that.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense without a relationship

Comment: I didn't catch your point. Why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: If you look at the Java code you wouldn't expect that deleting D C will be deleted because there is no reference